# Robots are still disallowed even without a robots.txt file

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I'm having trouble with a website I'm working on. I initially set up a robots.txt file to prevent robots from indexing it while I was working on it. However now its live and the robots.txt rile has been deleted but it still has not been crawled and shows that robots are disallowed access. EVen in the absence of a robots.txt file. The site is a wordpress based website - everything seems to suggest that there should be no block for any crawlers.

Running a search for `site:claimsadvicecentre.co.uk` should bring up atleast 5 pages however its only listing the main page.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Google webmaster tools is good for giving feedback of problems with crawling your site: https://www.google.com/webmasters/

Comment: What's happen in the .htaccess file - your robots file looks ok.

Comment: There shouldn't be a robots file to begin with.

Comment: its there. just delete it from the root of your site, you could just leave a blank one in place then it won't 404 http://claimsadvicecentre.co.uk/robots.txt

Comment: OMG! I swore I deleted it from my FTP...

Comment: I did it - put a blank robots file in place - this should solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, nothing seems immediately wrong. Instead, some of your assumptions appear to be wrong.

First, questions.
When you say: "but it [] shows that robots are disallowed" what is the "it" being referred to?

How long has it been since you deleted the robots file? That's not going to make any difference until you get crawled again.

Now, your search example suggests that you *have* been indexed, at least to some degree. But that doesn't mean the engines will decide *all* your pages will be worth actually returning as search results.

Beyond that, searches with the `site:` operator do not necessarily return everything indexed for a site, but only a selection. If you need to actually know how well your site's been crawled, you get that information from Webmaster Tools.

Comment: I guess its been almost like 5 days now since it has been deleted. When I mean it I'm referring to the results of the search for site:claimsadvicecentre.co.uk .

Comment: robots.txt is appears to still be in place http://claimsadvicecentre.co.uk/robots.txt

Comment: I just reuploaded a different robots.txt - can't for the life of me understand how come the file would still be there even after being deleted

Answer (score 0):

So the robots file still appears to be present but the code has changed since i looked at it first thing it now shows:-

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

But to **allow all**, it should be (what it was this morning)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

You can find some more examples in the wiki article on [Robots Exclusion Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard).

*Could it be that one of your wordpress plugins is auto generating a robots file?*

Answer (score 0):

To combine everything into one big answer, here's what you should do...

1. Make sure your robots.txt is correct.  Here's what it should look like if you want the crawlers to index everything on your site:

   User-agent: *
   Disallow:

   Please note that the *Allow* field is not officially supported by all crawlers (*Disallow* is the universally accepted field).
2. Create an XML Sitemap that lists the pages on your site.  You can do this manually, or you can use an automatic generator.
3. Register your site with Google Webmaster Tools.
  Submit your XML Sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools.

Once you've completed these steps, your site will be well on its way to being indexed.